# How to add an array as a column in existing csv file in python?

Tags: python, arrays, csv, dataframe, regression

I have an array of response variables which I have got using regression analysis by using further code.

```
SalePrice_baseline = reg2.predict(test)
```

The output looks like,

```
array([[ 103612.29783843],
       [  95608.74582384],
       [ 178230.07228516],
       ..., 
       [ 172559.98073767],
       [ 121881.65675305],
       [ 218179.82985471]])
```

I have an existing test csv file of all the input variables as test.csv. I want to add this array as a new column.

How do I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: read all columns from csv file, add column to columns in memory, write all columns to csv file.

Answer (score 1):

If the CSV file has the same number of lines as your vector, then
you can read a line as a string, then print it plus a comma plus the corresponding vector value

```
with open('a.csv') as inp:
    with open('b.csv', 'w') as out:
        for line, value in zip(inp, vector)
            line = line.rstrip()
            print(line, ',', value, sep='', file=out)
```

Comment: You could also use the built-in csv writer as in the [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40875757/6917168) with this algorithm. It will auto-escape values, allow you to easily change separators, etc.